# Which method ensures every picture has a equal probability of being shown

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random

I have created a program which shows random pictures every time a button is pressed. Every picture is different and is assigned a unique integer ID . A picture can be re-shown though it has been shown to the user before.

The following line of code generates the random card ID to be chosen:

`picCount` is the number of unique pictures.

`newPic` is the ID of the picture to be chosen.

```
var newPic = Math.floor((Math.random()*this.100)+1) % this.picCount;
```

I am wondering if i should change from

```
var newPic = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1) % this.picCount;
```

TO

```
var newPic = Math.floor((Math.random()*this.picCount)+1) % this.picCount;
```

to ensure equal distribution of the cards as my current method favours some cards more than others.

Is my analysis correct?

How do I make the picture shown to be more random?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the IDs are from 0 to picCount - 1, you should be able to just put

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*this.picCount);
```

to achieve a completely uniform distribution. Math.random() is more than enough for this purpose; pseudorandomness is fine in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here all pictures have the same probability:

```
var TotalNumberOfPics = 10;

// 1 to 10
var per = Math.floor((Math.random()*TotalNumberOfPics)+1);
```

Here it's based on picCount:

```
var TotalNumberOfPics = 10;

var Chances = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 };

var TotalChances = 0;

for (var i=0;i<TotalNumberOfPics; i++)
    TotalChances = TotalChances + Chances[i];

// 1 to TotalChances
var per = Math.floor((Math.random()*TotalChances)+1);

var selectedPic = 0;

for (var selectedPic=0;selectedPic<TotalNumberOfPics; selectedPic++)
if (per >= Chances[selectedPic])
per = per - Chances[selectedPic];

// we end up with selectedPic index in range [0,TotalNumberOfPics)
```